# NSRunLoop and dispatch queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I have a couple of questions on NSRunLoops in conjunction with dispatch queues.

In my application's delegate `applicaitonDidEnterBackground`, I'm creating a `UIBackgroundTask`.

Following that, I use a timer and run loop to execute a task a few minutes after the app is in the background:

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.myTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]  run];
        });
```

So here are my questions:

Is the above a valid approach or is there a better way to achieve a scheduled task while in the background?

Do I need to stop the run loop once my timer's method has fired? I recall from Apple's documentation that simply calling run on an NSRunLoop is not advisable, but I also understand that in GCD I don't have fine-grain control over which thread is returned.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not use the dispatch_source_t type and then call dispatch_source_set_timer?

Comment: You can either use dispatch timers as Dreaming In Binary said, or just schedule a standard `NSTimer` on the main thread. Either would be better than creating another run loop. But why run the timer in the background at all? Don't conflate the "background" state of the app with background threads.

Comment: By the way, when you do really do need run loop on background thread (and I don't suspect that this is such a case), when Apple advises against `run`, they're only saying that you really should use `while` loop with `runMode:beforeDate:`.

Comment: @Rob and Dreaming In Binary thanks for that, dispatch timers did not come to mind at all. I suppose I can further simply by calling dispatch_after? I presume this would be ok if the code is executing in applicaitonDIdEnterBackground. I'm looking at a 5 min delay. Seems to work on iOS7.1 as well :)

Comment: As Rob says, you seem to be confusing background threads with the app being in the background. These things are totally unrelated. Just schedule a timer on the run loop. Obviously be aware that your app can be stopped in the middle of the timer running. You are not supposed to continue running in the background unless you really, really have to.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's the point, I need to. Which is why I'm scheduling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler to allow for some extra time for my timer to fire.

Comment: Fine. Our point is merely that you still can run tasks on main thread during `beginBackgroundTask...`. You can use `NSTimer` on main run loop or `dispatch_after` to main queue in conjunction with `beginBackgroundTask...`.